# How can I migrate an RDS serverless cluster to a provisioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration, aws-dms

I know the question is normally the other way around, but it seems important to know how can we go back to a provisioned solution from a serverless cluster.

We will migrate to an Postgres RDS serverless cluster in a few days and we would like to know how can we go back to a provisioned cluster if something goes wrong with the serverless solution. I didn't find any answers, as DMS doesn't seem to allow serverless sources.

Is there any way to achieve this, other than using pg_dump?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of AWS RDS Aurora Serverless that you are using:

- For Serverless v1, just create a snapshot and [restore it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-restore-snapshot.html) to a provisioned cluster. Snapshots are compatible between provisioned clusters and Serverless v1.
- Serverless v2 uses the same clusters as provisioned instances (see the first paragraph of the [AWS Docs for Serverless v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.create-cluster.html)). Select the serverless instance of the cluster, click the "Modify" button and select another "DB instance class" under "Instance configuration". Note: You can also have serverless and provisioned instances in the same cluster, which allows for more complex migration paths like first adding a new instance, remove the old one and using writer instance promotion.

You may first want to test those methods with test data even though I validated them for you with empty databases.

Please also keep in mind that Severless v2 only released in April 2022 (after a long beta testing period solely with MySQL), so you may want to thoroughly test it if you want to use it in production.